# behavior of git branch in powerlevel10k

Tags: oh-my-zsh

I am using oh-my-zsh and powerlevel10k on Mac and I observed a weird behavior when using `git branch`. Instead of like other commands, like `git status` which will list the result in current terminal.
[image]

However, `git branch` is like into an editor mode and I have to press `q` to exit the mode to get back to terminal.
[image]

Anyone knows how to fix it, i.e., let the `git branch` command to show results in current terminal instead of entering into an editor mode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`git` is using the pager (usually `less` command) for its output.

you can configure it via [`core.pager`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-corepager) for all the `git` commands or use per command config [`pager.<cmd>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-pagerltcmdgt); there is also [`GIT_PAGER`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables) env variable

the easiest way to skip the paging for one time is to use `--no-pager` option for command; and to disable the paging completely [`git` documentation suggests](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-pagerltcmdgt):

> To disable pagination for all commands, set `core.pager` or `GIT_PAGER` to `cat`.

`git config --global core.pager cat`

you may experiment with setting the pager to `less -F -X`; this will make `less` command to page the content only if it does not fit the screen `-F`, and not to clean the terminal buffer `-X`

`git config --global core.pager 'less -F -X'`

or simply disable the pager for the `branch` command

`git config --global pager.branch false`

Answer (score 6):

It seems that since [version 2.16](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.16.0.txt#L87), git defaults to use the pagination for the `branch` command.

You can disable pagination for branch command only using

```
git config --global pager.branch false
```

[It seems to be working for your specific shell](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/issues/7466#issuecomment-454776650)